# PHP str_replace not correctly replacing number to string

Tags: php, str-replace

Can someone, please, explain me why php function `str_replace` not correctly replacing number to string?

```
$number      =   [1,5,10,15];
$text        =   ["one", "five", "ten", "fifteen"];

$replaced_1  =   str_replace($number, $text, 1); 
$replaced_5  =   str_replace($number, $text, 5); 
$replaced_10  =   str_replace($number, $text, 10);
$replaced_15  =   str_replace($number, $text, 15);

echo $replaced_1."<br>"; // one
echo $replaced_5."<br>"; // five
echo $replaced_10."<br>"; // one0
echo $replaced_15; // onefive
```

Same result with quotes: `$number = ["1","5","10","15"]`

Comment: What's the expected result? If you expect `ten`  instead of `one0`: replacing happens starting with the first element in the array, and that maps `1`  to `one`

Comment: @NicoHaase Replace number `10` to `ten` instead of `one0`

Comment: The issue is the _order_ you are doing the replacements in.  Your `1` is being replaced first.  There are three `1`s in your array.  `str_replace()` doesn't care that the `1` is part of a `10` or `15`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: sort the array by highest first, also you can get words of the numbers with NumberFormatter https://3v4l.org/SWqo1 so you wont need a second array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Str_replace() function replaces some characters with some other characters in a **string**.

Do you really have to work with str_replace? otherwise just do it with an array:

```
$numbers = [
    1 => "one",
    15 => "fifteen",
];

echo $numbers[15];
```

Comment: Please share more details. Your answer does not explain why the replacement works in some of the given cases, and not in one specific one

Comment: @NicoHaase This is an interesting question ;-) The context of str_replace seems wrong to me here. to get fifteen in the str_replace context this would be correct: ```$number = 15;
$text = 'Fifteen';
echo str_replace($number, $text, 15);```

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> If search or replace are arrays, their elements are processed first to last.

That means: the first replacement for the input `10` replaces the `1`  by `one`, returning `one0`. There's nothing more in the first array `$number`  that could match this result to anything

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with [Maik Lowrey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14807111/maik-lowrey) answer, however [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) was made for this.  With `str_replace` the `1` as well as the 1 in `10` and `15` will be replaced.  But with `strtr`:

> The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.

```
$replaced_1  =  strtr(1, array_combine($number, $text)); 
$replaced_5  =  strtr(5, array_combine($number, $text)); 
$replaced_10 =  strtr(10, array_combine($number, $text));
$replaced_15 =  strtr(15, array_combine($number, $text));
```